# Magnetic reconnection in MHD theory

Tags: plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

What does the MHD theory predict when two regions with magnetic field of opposed polarization interact? When we take in account the resistivity then we can observe a rearrangement of the topology due to magnetic reconnection but I am wondering what does the ideal MHD equations predict in that scenario.

Comment: Polarization isn't accounted for in ideal MHD equations, so what more than "nothing" do you want?

Comment: Maybe nothing is the thing but I would like more details, please. For example, what will happen with the overlapping regions of different polarization? What I was thinking is that if you have regions of opposite polarization interacting such that we can assume that the medium is ideal, then they will superimpose and they will just keep moving in opposite directions without changing their local topology after their interaction but I am not sure at all.

Comment: Again, ideal MHD only considers magnetic fields and nothing else. If you want to look at non-ideal scenario, that's fine but you may want to clarify "polarization" because I'm only aware of [polarization denisty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density), which involves dielectrics (and in plasmas, this would be zero).